# Overloaded assignment operator for copy/move operations?

Tags: c++, copy, move

I'm going over the basics of overloaded operators, specifically the assignment operator. I'm trying to understand the use of overloading in dictating copy and move behavior by following this:

[operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

I find the example they give to be quite unclear.

This is the basic code I've written so far to illustrate overloading. How can this code be edited to illustrated the use of overloading in customizing copy and move behavior?

```
class Distance
{
public:
    int feet, inches;

    Distance()
    {
        feet = 0;
        inches = 0;
    }

    Distance(int f, int i)
    {
        feet = f;
        inches = i;
    }

    auto operator=(Distance &D)->void //Use operator to perform additional operation (adding 100)
    {
        feet = D.feet + 100;
        inches = D.inches + 100;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Distance D1;
    D1.feet = 10;
    D1.inches = 12;
    Distance D2;
    D2 = D1;
    std::cout << D2.feet << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't use assignment operator like that (even if you can). Assignment operator with additional operation could be used for example for counting how many assignments was made. Altering data this way leads to confusion and human error during use of the interface. You expect the code to work in some way, in case of assignment operator, it is copying values. Just follow how built-in types work and implement your overloaded operators that way. You wouldn't multiply volumes for operator+(), right? That wouldn't make any sense.

Additional operation in this case could be e.g.:

```
static int assignmentCount = 0;

auto operator=(Distance &D)->void 
   {
     feet=D.feet;
     inches=D.inches;
     std::cout << "Made assignment"; //Just some debug stuff
     assignmentCount++;              //Count assignments made
   }
```

Don't forget, that you have put there void as return type, which disables you to do following D1=D2=D3, which could be useful in some cases. Returning reference to receiving value is common practice.

I recommend reading Professional C++ by Marc Gregoire, or one of Stroupstrup's books. My recent experience is, that online sources can lead to some sort of confusion and books are generally better for learning basics.

Comment: Is it still unclear, even after reading it? Or what exactly worries you?

Comment: For those who don't understand - OP posted comment stating, that Stroupstrup has whole chapter about assignment operators, just to make it clear.